# Error, referencing shape file data table (x@data) in nested loop, plot(), if else, dataframe

Tags: r, loops, plot, shapefile

Update:  adding an example.  The shapefile destination and read directories just need to be pointed towards a particular user. Thanks for any comments.

```
a<-rep("Baker",10)
b<-rep("Columbia",10)
m<-factor(data<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))
n<-m
e<-sample(c(runif(10,min=0,max=1)))
f<-sample(c(runif(10,min=0,max=3)))
g<-c(a,b)
h<-c(m,n)
i<-c(e,f)
t5<-data.frame(g,h,i)
colnames(t5)<-c("Regions_RR","Name","Value")
url2<-"http://navigator.state.or.us/sdl/data/shapefile/k24/orcnty24.zip" 
work.dir<-"c:/Users/.../Downloads"
file1<-basename(url2)
download.file(url2,file1)
unzip(file1,exdir=work.dir)
require(rgdal)
s<-readOGR("C:/Users/.../Downloads",layer="orcnty24")
summary(s)
s@data$altName
```

I want to create multi-panel plots, which consist of a column of panels in which are plotted shapefiles and a second column of panels in which are plotted data, corresponding to a single region polygon in the shapefile.  Each row represents a different region, so I want to color a single ploygon in each plot.

I can't get the syntax right for the plot statement for the shapefile. My latest attempt is below, using d_ply() in the col= statement. That generates an

```
"error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot'
```

If what I'm asking doesn't come across I can provide some example data, but maybe there is a simple solution.  Am I going about this the wrong way?  Do I need to convert the shapefile attribute table to some other object?  Thanks for any comments.

s= polygon shapefile

s@data = shapefile attribute table

t5= dataframe

```
plot.new()                                  #open plot
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
par(cex=0.6)
par(mar=c(3,3,0,0),oma=c(1,1,1,1))
par(tcl=-0.25)

d_ply(t5,"Regions_RR",function(y)   {       #cycle through df by region
    for (i in 1:4)  {                       #cycle through panels
      if (i %in% c(1,3))                    #plot shapefiles in panels 1 & 3

      plot(s, col=ifelse(d_ply(as.data.frame(s@data),"altName", function (z)
            {
             z=y}),1,0))
      if (i %in% c(2,4))                    #plot data in panels 2 & 4
      d_ply(t5,"Name",function(x) {
      plot(data=x,(Value~y), xlab="", ylab=unique(x$Name), las =2,  par(mar=c(12,5,4,2)+.1))  
    })
    }
    })
```

What I've tried:

On its own this works fine, the plot is one case of what I want:

```
  plot(s, col=ifelse(s@data$Regions_all=="Coastal",1,0))
```

This statements gets an error:

```
 plot(s, col=ifelse(s@data$Regions_all==y,1,0))
```

As does this one (because not cycling through s@data, I think):

```
 Error in s@data$Regions_all > y :

 comparison of these types is not implemented
 In addition: Warning message:
 In storage.mode(test) <- "logical" :
 Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.data.frame") for ">"
```

As does this one:

```
 plot(s, col=ifelse(s@data$Regions_all=y,1,0))

 Error: unexpected '=' in:
 "      if (i %in% c(1,3))
 plot(s, col=ifelse(s@data$Regions_all="
```

As does this one:

```
  plot(s, col=ifelse(s@data$Regions_all==t5$Regions_RR[[y]],1,0)
  Error in `[[.default`(t5$Regions_RR, y) :

  attempt to select more than one element
```

Comment: Can you make a small reproducible example?

Comment: At the top of the post is some sample code for a df and shapefile.  Does that help?  Thanks for assisting.